# Avoid double backslash in windows path

Tags: python, path, operating-system

my program should parse /classifiers folder and go throught some calc. Here is a paths for folders:

```
classifiers_path = os.path.join('C:/Users/feature/classifiers')
```

Here is a lines of code, that parses that folder:

```
        for i in os.path.join(classifiers_path + '/*.pkl'):
        # Pulling the model from the path
        model = joblib.load(i)
```

While debugging i have paths like this:

```
C:/Users/feature/classifiers\\T1.pkl
```

So it breaks with FileNotFoundError,
How to avoid this double \, and it should be written, for unix/windows? Thanks

Comment: The double \\ is for display, as it has to escape the character.

Comment: The error is because you are doing a `for` on a string and not on `glob.glob(`.

Comment: Windows path related issues are discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/windows-path-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is stated in the comments, you should be iterating through the files in the directory, not through the string resulting from `os.path.join()`. So instead, iterate through the list of files in your `classifiers_path` directory resulting from passing it to `os.listdir()` like this:

```
for i in os.listdir(os.path.join(classifiers_path)):
        if i.endswith('.pkl'):
            model = joblib.load(i)
```